# manually calculate excel power law r^2

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble manually calculating the r^2 (coefficient of determination) for a power law curve when adding the trendline in Excel.  I can't obtain the same value as Excel.  I try to linearize the data by taking the logarithm (base 10) of the y-values, and then calculating the r^2 for linear data, but I can't obtain the same result as Excel's power law r^2.  Here is an example.  Note that I am well aware that the data I will post here does not even come close to following a power law curve, but that's not the point, and it was the data I was testing at the time.

Let's say I have the following x and y values.

```
x   y
2   0.25
3   0.25
4   0.3125
5   0.0625
6   0.0625
7   0.0625
```

When I put this into excel, and add a trendline to the graph, Excel shows me that the power law equation is y=0.9414*x^(-1.395) and the r^2 value is 0.6519.

Now I want to obtain this same value manually.  First I linearize the data by taking the logarithm base 10 of all of the points.  Note that I also tried taking the natural logarithm, but the end result is the same value.  Now my new x and y are as follows.

```
x   y
2   -0.602059991
3   -0.602059991
4   -0.505149978
5   -1.204119983
6   -1.204119983
7   -1.204119983
```

I then calculate the r^2 of this "linear" data using the formula on Microsoft's page.

r^2 = (sum((x-xbar)(y-ybar))/(sqrt(sum((x-xbar)^2))*sqrt(sum((y-ybar)^2))))^2

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/RSQ-function-d7161715-250d-4a01-b80d-a8364f2be08f

I obtain an r^2 value of 0.712549414.  Note that if I graph this linear data, add a linear trendline, and show the r^2 then the value is also 0.712549414.

Why doesn't linearizing the data and calculating the r^2 value (0.712549414) give me the same value as the r^2 shown on the graph for the power law curve with the original data (0.6519)?  How can I manually calculate the value shown in the power law curve for the original data?

Comment: Consider asking this question on a math forum on Stack Exchange instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes 0.6519 is the correct answer.  I just double-checked.  Note that I did not realize my data would post in such a strange way.  I originally had two columns.

Comment: Perhaps the x and y values are more clearly understood when represented like this: (x,y): (2,0.25),(3,0.25),(4,0.3125),(5,0.0625),(6,0.0625),(7,0.0625)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the log of both x and y to linearize it, then you get the same answer both ways i.e.

```
x'=log(x)
y'=log(y)
```

and do the correlation using x' and y'.

Because if the formula is in the form

```
y=xk
```

where k is a constant, taking logs gives you

```
log(y)=klog(x)
```

so

```
y'=kx'
```

which is a straight line.

Comment: Oh wow.  Yes you are correct!  The answer was so simple.  I'm surprised I didn't try that.  Thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome! Think I might add a bit more detail just to explain why.

Comment: I see.  That makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more simplified version of the equation can be used to calculate r^2.
Let y = f(x), if f(x) is linear, then

```
  ybar = average(yi)
  R^2 = sum((f(xi) - ybar)^2) / sum((yi-ybar)^2)
```

In the power law case, y = a*x^b.
Then both x and y need to be linearized by taking ln on both sides, 
the equation becomes ln(y) = ln(a) + b * ln(x)

```
 ybar = average(ln(yi))
 R^2 = sum((ln(a) + b * ln(xi) - ybar)^2) / sum((ln(yi) - ybar)^2)
```